# How to pass a result from a Shell Script to the next step inside Automator

Tags: bash, macos, automator

I am using automator to create a Finder service to get the length of all selected videos and display on a dialog.

So, the service will work like this:

1. I select a bunch of videos
2. I right click and run the service.

I have found this Bash script on the web that works perfectly.

```
times=()
for f in *.mov; do
    _t=$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | grep -o " [0-9:.]*, " | head -n1 | tr ',' ' ' | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
    times+=("$_t")
done
echo "${times[@]}" | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc
```

I am trying to adapt that for automator. So, my service so far is equal to this:

I have a first step that receives the movie files from Finder and passes to this `Run Shell Script`

```
times=()
for f in "$@"; do
    _t=$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | grep -o " [0-9:.]*, " | head -n1 | tr ',' ' ' | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
    times+=("$_t")
done
total="${times[@]}" | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc
```

I was forced to change the `for` loop to this

```
for f in "$@"; do
```

I understand this is how automator enumerates all files received. Files are received as arguments.

I have changed the last line to

```
total="${times[@]}" | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc
```

To create a variable called `total` that can hold the total number of seconds of all videos.

Now I need to pass this variable to the next step and display it on a dialog.

Two questions:

1. how do I do that?
2. are the changes I did correct?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, changing the `for` loop in your shell script from:

```
for f in *.mov; do
```

to

```
for f in "$@"; do
```

is correct. The `$@` is all the parameters passed to the shell script, which in your scenario will be the pathname of each selected movie file(s).

> *Now I need to pass this variable to the next step and display it on a dialog*

To achieve this you need to:

1. [`echo`](https://ss64.com/osx/echo.html) the `total` at the end of the shell script. So change the last line in your second example shell script to the following:

   ```sh
   times=()
   for f in "$@"; do
     _t=$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | grep -o " [0-9:.]*, " | \
        head -n1 | tr ',' ' ' | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
     times+=("$_t")
   done
   echo "${times[@]}" | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc   # <-- change last line to this
   ```
2. Next in *Automator* add a `Run AppleScript` action after your current `Run Shell Script` action. To find the `Run AppleScript` action in *Automator* you can:

   - Select `Library` at the top of the panel/column on the left:
   - In the search field type: <kbd>Run AppleScript</kbd> and drag the `Run AppleScript` action into the canvas area below your current `Run Shell Script` action.
3. Enter the following AppleScript into the newly added `Run AppleScript` action:

   ```
   on run {totalDuration}
     set dialogText to (totalDuration as text) & " seconds"
     tell application "Finder" to display dialog dialogText with title ¬
         "Total Duration" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon 1
   end run
   ```

#### Example Automator Workflow:

The completed canvas area of your Automator Service/Workflow should now appear something like this:

[image]

**Note:**

1. I don't have the `ffmpeg` utility available on the mac I'm currently using, therefore the shell script shown in the screenshot above uses the built-in [`mdls`](https://ss64.com/osx/mdls.html) utility to obtain the duration of each move instead.

   Here is that code:

   ```sh
   total_duration=0

   for f in "$@"; do
     duration=$(mdls -name kMDItemDurationSeconds -raw -nullMarker 0 "$f")
     total_duration=$(echo "$total_duration" + "$duration" | bc)
   done

   echo "$total_duration"
   ```
2. The other minor difference in that screenshot is the code shown in the `Run AppleScript` action. This just does some rounding which is probably not necessary given your shell script that you want to use. Using the AppleScript shown in the aforementioned point number 3 should be OK.

Comment: BRILLIANT! But I was forced to make one change to make it work for me: `set dialogText to (totalDuration as text) & " seconds"`. The line `Tell application Finder to display dialog` can be replaced by just `display dialog...`. PERFECT. THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @SpaceDog - Thank you, and yes I realized the `(totalDuration as text)` part was missing.